# How to use standard Button style in WPF ToolBar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, toolbar

I want the Buttons in my WPF ToolBar to look like standard Buttons.  That is, I want them to use the default Button style, but the ToolBar applies its own "ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey" style to the Buttons.  I have tried this...

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Content="A Button" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" />
</ToolBar>
```

... but the Button in the ToolBar still looks just like a TextBlock (no border, background, etc.).

Comment: Your example works for me. I have a toolbar with a standard button.

Answer (score 4):

Your example works fine for me on Windows 10.

You could also try this:

```
<ToolBar>
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" />
    </ToolBar.Resources>
    <Button Content="A Button" />
</ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use without any style,

```
<ToolBar>
       <Button Content="A Button" />
</ToolBar>
```

**EDIT**
Misread the question, this should work fine without any issue

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Content="A Button" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" />
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: That would actually remove the standard style and make it look like a textblock which is the opposite of what he wants.